# how to improve GAN training for text?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, seq2seq

I want to generate sequences. I have a seq2seq model as generator and a discriminator which take hidden states to distinguished whether a sequence is fake or real. I train my seq2seq, and it works well when I train that network alone, but The main problem is when it comes to GAN, I cannot generate any real sequences and the sequences that are generated like this.

```
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

And here the real sequences are look like

```
PDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKV
```

here is my optimizer

```
optimizerD = torch.optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr=0.01)
optimizerG = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

the loss function is BCE loss and this is the way I train my GAN

```
        disc.zero_grad()
        #Real data
        errD_real = loss_func(disc(src), y_real)
        errD_real.backward()
        ## Train with all-fake batch
        # Classify all fake batch with D. We will save this to re-use for the 2nd step.
        fake = model(src, trg) #***x**~fake~ =G(**z**)*
        # Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch, note use of fake.detach()
        errD_fake = loss_func(disc(fake.detach()), y_fake) #*ℓ ( D( x~real~) , y~real~)*
        # Calculate the gradients for this batch
        errD_fake.backward()
        # Add the gradients from the all-real and all-fake batches
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        # Update D
        optimizerD.step()
            
              
        

        model.zero_grad()
        # Calculate G's loss based on this output
        errG = loss_func(disc(fake), y_real) #*ℓ ( D(**x**~fake~) , y~real~)*
        # Calculate gradients for G
        errG.backward()
        # Update G
        optimizerG.step()
```

I even use WGAN but still could not have any improvement this is my training with WGAN

```
              disc.zero_grad()

              output = disc(src)

              errD_real = -torch.mean(output)

              D_x = output.mean().item()


              fake = model(src, trg)

              # Classify all fake batch with D
              output = disc(fake.detach())


              # Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch
              errD_fake = torch.mean(output)

              # Calculate the gradients for this batch
              D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()

              # Add the gradients from the all-real and all-fake batches
              errD = -(errD_real - errD_fake)
              errD.backward()
              # Update D
              optimizerD.step()

              #Clipping weights
              for p in disc.parameters():
                p.data.clamp_(-0.01, 0.01)

        
              model.zero_grad()

              fake = model(src, trg)


              # Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
              output = disc(fake)

  
              errG = -torch.mean(output)

              # Calculate gradients for G
              errG.backward()
              D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()

              # Update G
              optimizerG.step()
```

The loss function of both generator and discriminator are changing well in first 50 epochs and it is like training but after that It stays almost constant and changes only slightly
Sorry that my question is too long. Do you have any suggestion for improvement and make this GAN works?

Comment: What are the loss and accuracy you get? Does your model seems like its training? You need to add some more details

Comment: @sagi I edit my question and add some information about loss. The model looks like it is not training, specially after 50 epochs losses are in range 1.4 for discriminator and 0.7 generator